# Giant cover photo (full width, full height) in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running Bootstrap 2.3 and Wordpress and my goal is to make a giant cover picture similar to this: http://www.platetheslate.com/ (only with my navbar on the top.) with the article below it.

I'm trying to achieve it through my header file, with code like this at the very top:

```
<style> 
.cut img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
} 
</style> 

<div class="cut">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

But it's not achieving a similar effect, and it's leaving a considerably large gap between the menu bar and the cover picture. I'm kind of new at this but would love to get this down. If there is a better way of going about this or anything, I'm all ears. Or eyes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

   html { 
      background: url(your-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also try a jquery solution:
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: Cool thanks. I feel like I should know this but, how do I implement this? This is what my code looks like at the top of my header file: 

`<style> 
.cut img { 
  background: url() no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style> 

<div class="cut">
</div>`  - but nothing shows up on my page.

Comment: Ok, I updated it but it's pushing it to the background and not full loading the picture for some reason. I'm trying to make it like the example linked above, so it kinda pushes everything else (like the article) below the picture, except for the nav bar.

Comment: Ok I figured out it is fully loading the background, but it's stuck behind all the foreground content and not pushing everything below it. Any idea how to do that in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

this is how you code shoudl look like if you include Jason B codeld

```
<style> 
   html { 
      background: url(your-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
.cut img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
} 
</style> 

<div class="cut">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't fully load the background, and it's loading 2 of the same picture (with the same problem where the picture on top is leaving a gap between itself and the navigation bar.)

Comment: Ok I figured out it is fully loading the background, but it's stuck behind all the foreground content and not pushing everything below it. Any idea how to do that in Bootstrap?